# Is it worth buying more expensive USB 3.0 case for old laptop HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I am planning to buy an external USB case for my dead (bought in 2010) laptop's 2.5" hard disk. Would a USB 3.0 case be actually faster than USB 2.0 for it, or does it not matter because HDD cannot match USB 3.0 speeds as mentioned here:

[When and where to determine if a USB 3.0 HDD enclosure can actually work at USB 3.0 speeds?](https://superuser.com/questions/1355480/when-and-where-to-determine-if-a-usb-3-0-hdd-enclosure-can-actually-work-at-usb)?

Comment: Most any drive can match/beat the faster 3.0. I use several of them and way faster than my old 2.0 enclosures.

Comment: Yes a USB case will be much faster but you may only need it once. Hook up what you have and recover the documents overnight.

Comment: Considering that an external USB 3 enclosure costs next to nothing, why are you even asking this question?  It would be a completely different question if you already had a 2.0 enclosure in hand...

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have a few hard disks that I plan to use  later as external portable drives so will need to buy more than one cases. Don't want to spend extra if no additional benefit. Every penny counts :-)